# crosshair on cursor

Tags: lubuntu, cursor

In the past I've used a handy utility on Windows called "CrossHair" - it brings up a crosshair over the whole screen, centered on the cursor location -see a screenshot here - http://www.cohjs.org/CrossHair.jpg.html
I downloaded it years ago, and today it's only available on archive.org.

I installed it on Wine, and it works partially but very clunky - only when the configuration window is open + active, roving version only when you continuously hold down the hotkey, and it flickers.

Anybody familiar with something like this that'd work in Lubuntu? Nothing from a search on Synaptic or the web. This page
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Magnification#Implemented_Features
appears to describe something promising but I'm relatively new to Lubuntu, and I have not found Gnomemag in Synaptic or in my installation.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I wonder if you could just switch your default cursor in your cursor theme for a 1px cross that's as wide and high as double your screen?

Comment: <- doesn't appear to be possible, max X11 cursor size is 256px according to GIMP.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092774/temporarily-switch-to-a-full-screen-hairline-cursor/1095983?noredirect=1#comment1805453_1095983

Comment: Thanks WinEu. In that related question, this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1095133/618054 suggests screenruler - that's in the repo + available thru Synaptic, and is a real good solution for my needs.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll be glad to accept it. Thx.